# What type of datastructure to use with this type of data format?

Tags: java, data-structures

The following is the example of structure of data I'm working with -

```
    {
        {DATA IDX1 -> {INFO ID1, INFO ID2,  INFO ID3}}, 
        {DATA IDX2 -> {INFO ID1, INFO ID2}}, 
        {DATA IDX3 -> {INFO ID5, INFO ID6}}, 
        // etc...
    }
```

- All data is in strings include sublist are string values.
- Sublist values might duplicate other sublist values.
- I need to be able to get size and iterate through sublists.
- Essentially each sublist has reference ID that I need to get to as well as sublist IDs that associate with that list.

I can't figure out which one will be most suitable. I might go with the one I can implement first.

Should I use `ArrayList`, `List`, `LinkedList` or `HashMap` with a list?

Comment: a `java.util.Map` or better a `Multimap` (see guava one for example)?

Comment: I would say a map of String as key and list as value

Comment: `Map<String,List<RandomInfo>>`

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
Hashmap <String, List<Object>> dataMap;
```

So that you get a list of objects when you use the statement

```
dataMap.get("DATA ID1");
```

You can go through the List items to find out the type and process the data accordingly.

Comment: Why not List<Strings> instead of List<Object>?

Comment: Oh yeah, I thought you meant "Random" type :) when you mentioned "Random INFO ID5". I see that it is a String, so Hashmap <String, List<String>> is better.

Comment: If have a chance maybe you can help me iterate with this particular structure? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721517/java-iterateing-through-hasmap-with-list/22721586?noredirect=1#22721586

Comment: What would I use to allow duplicate keys?