# JAVA Iterateing through Hasmap with list

Tags: java, hashmap

I need iterate through hashmap and get key value which should be a string and all values within that key which is a list of strings that have strings?

Psuedo code

```
static HashMap<String, List<String>> vertices  = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
{

       String key = vertices.getKey at first postions;

    for (int x = 0; x < size of sublist of the particular key; x++)
       {
              String value = vertices key sublist.get value of sublist at (i);

          }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: iterate through HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap)

Comment: What about particular situation of it being a list?  How do I get the list of that particular key?  I also need the string value of that key as well as the values of the list?

Comment: Should I delete this post?

Comment: Can I delete this post, moderator? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over `HashMap` directly, as there is no numeric index of values within `HashMap`. Instead `key` values are used, in your case of type `String`. Therefore the values don't have a particular order. However, if you want, you can construct a set of entries and iterate over that, using `vertices.entrySet()`.

```
for (Entry<String, List<String>> item : vertices.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Vertex: " + item);
    for (String subitem : item.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(subitem);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about getting values of the list of each key?

Comment: @MAXGEN You can try foreach loop, such as in given example.

Answer (score 1):

Try `vertices.keySet();`

It gives a Set of all keys in the map. Use it in a for loop like below

```
for (String key : vertices.keySet()) {
   for (String value : vertices.get(key)) { 
       //do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: How do iterate the list and String value would be list object instead of string?

Comment: @MAXGEN In this, `vertices.get(key)` is the list, and each `String value` is an element of the `List` value for `key`. The second loop _is_ iterating over the list.